# Setting range for table in Excel file

Tags: excel, axapta, excel-interop, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am generating Excel file in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009. I would like to create a table in Excel from 9th row. Even though I set a range, the table always shows at cell A1.

```
SysExcelRange           xlsRange;
SysExcelListObject      listObj;
#define.ListObjectName("xlGuess")
```

`...`

```
xlsRange = xlsWorkSheet.range("A9");
listObj = xlsWorkSheet.listObjects().add(xlsRange, #ListObjectName);
```

[image]

I've also tried to set full range like "A9:E13" and "A9:A13", but it didn't work either. Probably, it's possible to do it with COM objects but I couldn't achive it.
Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in the Excel wrapper of AX.
If I changed one line to pass the actual range to the underlying COM object then it seems to work; have a look at the screenshot for what I have changed.

[image]

With a AOT job like this

```
public static client void TestJob()
{
    #define.ListObjectName("xlGuess")

    SysExcelApplication     xlsApp;
    SysExcelWorksheet       xlsWorksheet;
    SysExcelRange           xlsRange;
    SysExcelListObject      listObj;
    ;

    xlsApp = SysExcelApplication::construct();
    xlsApp.workbooks().add();
    xlsWorksheet = xlsApp.activeSheet();
    xlsRange = xlsWorksheet.range("A9:C12");
    listObj = xlsWorkSheet.listObjects().add(xlsRange, #ListObjectName);
    xlsApp.visible(true);
}
```

it will open an Excel file like this:

[image]

Comment: That is similar to the code in AX 2012, but there it also checks if the `_range` object is `null`. If yes, the old version is used, other wise the fixed version. So this code may fail if the method is called without a range.